# How to authenticate google client to use youtube API in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

Hi guys i try to list all channels or atleast 1 channel exists in my google account, but i stuck at error page that tell me "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.Continued use requires signup.". Here is my config and my code (I coding on Laravel 5.1 ):

Step 1 : I pull "google-api-client-php" via composer and config like this in composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
}

"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google"
    ],
},
```

Step 2 : I create file google.php  in config/google.php to store my secretID,clientId ...

```
return [
    'app_name'             => '<my_project_name>',
    'client_id'            => '<my_project_client_id>',
    'client_secret'        => '<my_project_client_secret>',
    'api_key'              => '<my_project_api_key>',
    'service_account_name' => '<my_project_service_account_name>'
];
```

Step 3 : I create OAuth on console.developers.google.com with options :

- Application Type : Web application
- Authorized JavaScript origins : http://iceo.dev/ (my localhost web app)
- Authorized redirect URIs : http://iceo.dev/googles/channels.

Step 4 : I create Route for this redirect URL :

- Route::get('googles/channels','GoogleController@channels');

Step 5 : Create Controller named GoogleController with function:

```
public function channels(Google $google){
    return $google->getChannels();
}
```

Step 6 : I create a model named Google.php in App\Google.php :

```
protected $client;

protected $service;

function __construct()
{
    $client_id            = Config::get( 'google.client_id' );
    $client_secret        = Config::get( 'google.client_secret' );
    $service_account_name = Config::get( 'google.service_account_name' );
    $key                  = Config::get( 'google.api_key' );
    $applicationName      = Config::get( 'google.app_name' );
    $this->client = new \Google_Client();
    $this->client->setApplicationName( $applicationName );

}

public function getChannels()
{
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/googles/channels';

    $this->client->setClientId( Config::get( 'google.client_id' ) );
    $this->client->setClientSecret( Config::get( 'google.client_secret' ) );
    $this->client->setScopes( ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'] );
    $this->client->setRedirectUri( $redirect );
    $this->client->setApplicationName( Config::get( 'google.app_name' ) );
    $this->client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
    $this->service = new \Google_Service_YouTube( $this->client );

    $results = $this->service->channels->listChannels( 'contentDetails', [ 'mine' => true ] );

    return $results;
}
```

This is my result when i access my url iceo.dev/googles/channels :

Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 79:
Error calling GET googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Where do i wrong or i missing something ? plese guide me.